# how can I do a wrapper, for mat-select, and inside it will be another wrapp for mat-option, and the, use it in another components

Tags: angular, typescript, components

how can I do a wrapper, for mat-select, and inside it will be another wrapp for mat-option, and the, use it in another components

select.html

```
    <mat-select>
  <app-option></app-option>
</mat-select>
```

select.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  OnInit,
  Input,
  ViewChildren,
  QueryList,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CustFormControlDirective } from 'src/app/forms/cust-form-control';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { OptionComponent } from '../option/option.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: SelectComponent }],
})
export class SelectComponent extends CustFormControlDirective<string> {}
```

option.html

```
<mat-option></mat-option>
```

option.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-option',
  templateUrl: './option.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./option.component.scss'],
})
export class OptionComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

app.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <app-select></app-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning the use of `<app-select>` inside a `<mat-form-field>`, you'll have to implement `MatFormFieldControl` interface. You can see it [here, on the docs](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-form-field-control).

Concerning your `<app-option>`, I don't think it's possible, as `MatSelect` [expect to find `MatOption`as its children](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/668f79193bd3a1f8bf4830a66098f134d2fb596e/src/material/select/select.ts#L365):

```js
...
@ContentChildren(MatOption, {descendants: true}) options: QueryList<MatOption>;
...
```

The `descentants: true` above is not enough to run a query that crosses your `app-option` component to find `mat-option` inside it. It just works with the content placed directly in `mat-select` `ng-content`, or nested `ng-content`'s, placed directly in `mat-select` template, for example:

```html
<mat-select>
  <app-select>
    <mat-option></mat-option>
  </app-select>
</mat-select>
```

But I think that by doing things this way is not what you imagining. With some hard work maybe you can grab a reference o that `mat-option` inside `app-select` but to do anything with it after that would be an overwhelming task.

Answer (score 1):

so

option.html

```
<mat-option [value]="value">{{ text }}</mat-option>
```

option.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-option',
  templateUrl: './option.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./option.component.scss'],

})
export class OptionComponent
  implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: string;
  @Input() text: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

select.html

```
<mat-select>
  <mat-option *ngFor="let option of options" [value]="option.value">{{
    option.text
  }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

select.ts

```
import {
  Component,
  QueryList,
  ContentChildren,
  AfterViewInit,
} from '@angular/core';
import { CustFormControlDirective } from 'src/app/forms/cust-form-control';
import { MatFormFieldControl } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { OptionComponent } from '../option/option.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-select',
  templateUrl: './select.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./select.component.scss'],
  providers: [{ provide: MatFormFieldControl, useExisting: SelectComponent }],
})
export class SelectComponent extends CustFormControlDirective<string>
  implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(OptionComponent) options: QueryList<OptionComponent>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {}
}
```

my-app.html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <app-select>
    <app-option [value]="" [text]="'None'"></app-option>
    <app-option [value]="true" [text]="'True'"></app-option>
    <app-option [value]="false" [text]="'False'"></app-option>
    <app-option [value]="false" [text]="'three'"></app-option>
  </app-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Works like a charm; option.html can be dropped given that select.html is now taking over the rendering.